# Retrieving entity from context after Add() yet before SaveChanges() has been called

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

Let's assume I have a file with multiple rows each representing a `Person`, the `Person` entity has an `identity column` that is also the `primary key`.  Assuming that a `Person` can be repeated in the file, if it is, perhaps I want to do a last entry wins scenario.  In the example below I use a repository to retrieve a person from the database by the social security number.  The issue is that when the same SSN shows up again in the file, the repository still returns a null, even though technically that person with that SSN has already been added to the context (`SaveChanges` hasn't been called yet).  I realize I can work around this by tracking myself which `Person` objects have already been added.  I am wondering what is the best practice for this scenario.
Thanks.

```
foreach(row in fileRows)
{
    Person person = personRepository.GetBySSN(row.SSN);

    if(person == null)
    {
        //insert logic
    }
    else
    {
        //update logic
    }
}

personRepository.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Duplicates? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5719990/how-do-i-view-an-entityset-and-uncommitted-changes  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383485/entity-framework-4-and-transactions-do-uncommitted-changes-affect-select-results

Comment: I respectfully disagree.  Even though these are similar topics I am wondering what the best practice is when working through repositories.  I realize if I have direct access to the EF context I will have the ability to find out if certain SSN is added.  Being that I work through the abstraction of repositories, I am wondering what the best practice is.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I haven't found anything regarding best practices so I'll post my solution.  I know many other posts refer to the fact that the EF context provides mechanisms for looking into it and seeing if a particular entity is in attached state.  Being that I work through repositories (my business layer has no direct access to the EF context), my choice is either offloading this sort of logic into the repository, or attempt to solve it in the business layer.  My feeling is that this task is really a business concern and not a data access layer concern.

```
Dictionary<string, Person> newPeople = ...

foreach(row in fileRows)
{
    Person person;

    //if the person is already tracked by the dictionary, work with it, if not use the repository
    if(!newPeople.TryGetValue(row.SSN, out person))
    {
        person = personRepository.GetBySSN(row.SSN);
    }

    if(person == null)
    {
        //insert logic

        //keep track that this person is already in line for inserting
        newPeople.Add(row.SSN, person);
    }
    else
    {
        //update logic
    }
}

personRepository.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 14):

I think I can give the same answer I gave [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6990618/querying-objects-after-addobject-before-savechanges)

To persist an entity you usually add it to it's `DbSet` in the context.

For example

```
var bar = new Bar();
bar.Name = "foo";
var context = new Context();
context.Bars.Add(bar);
```

Surprisingly, querying `context.Bars`, the just added entity cannot be found

```
var howMany = context.Bars.Count(b => b.Name == "foo");
// howMany == 0
```

After `context.SaveChanges()` the same line will result `1`

The `DbSet` seems unaware to changes until they're persisted on db.

Fortunately, each `DbSet` has a `Local` property that acts like the `DbSet` itself, but it reflect all in-memory operations

```
var howMany = context.Bars.Local.Count(b => b.Name == "foo");
// howMany == 1
```

You can also use `Local` to add entities

```
context.Bars.Local.Add(bar);
```

and get rid of the weird behavior of Entity Framework.

Comment: So if I want the `Count` of both unsaved and saved entities, I would have to do `context.Bars.Count + context.Bars.Local.Count`?

Comment: @RuudLenders No, context.Bars.Local should contain both the unsaved entities as well as those already in the DB.

Comment: I have to correct myself: context.Bars.Local contains both, as long as you queried context.Bars at least once before. So you shouldn't rely on context.Bars.Local to have all data, but you can't just sum up those two Counts either.

Answer (score 1):

Modify your `GetBySSN` as follows:

```
public Person GetBySSN(string ssn) 
{
    Person p = context.ObjectStateManager
                      .GetObjectStateEntries(~EntityState.Deleted)
                      .Where(e => !e.IsRelationship)
                      .Select(e => e.Entity)
                      .OfType<Person>()
                      .SingleOrDefault(p => p.SSN = ssn);

    if (p == null) 
    {
        p = context.People.SingleOrDefault(p => p.SSN = ssn);
    }

    return p;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ladislav.  That's certainly another way to go about it.  If you look at my solution above I task the business logic with tracking what has already been added.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go Ladislav's route and query the ObjectStateManager then you may wish to use an extension method like the following:

```
public static IEnumerable<TEntity> LoadedEntities<TEntity>(this ObjectContext Context)
{
    return Context.ObjectStateManager
        .GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added | EntityState.Modified | EntityState.Unchanged)
        .Where(e => !e.IsRelationship).Select(e => e.Entity).OfType<TEntity>();
}
```

This would allow you to then do something like this:

```
Person p = context.LoadedEntities<Person>().SingleOrDefault(p => p.SSN = ssn);
if (p != null)
    return p;
return context.People.SingleOrDefault(p => p.SSN = ssn);
```