# Querying objects after AddObject before SaveChanges?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

In EntityFramework, is that possible to query the objects that have just been added to the context using AddObject but before calling the SaveChanges method?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can query objects like this,

```
context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added).Select(obj => obj.Entity).OfType<TheEntityType>()
```

this will query the objects which are in added state. If you want other states too you can pass all other states to `GetObjectStateEntries` method like this.

```
GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added | EntityState.Modified | EntityState.Unchanged)
```

Answer (score 33):

To persist an entity you usually add it to it's `DbSet` in the context.

For example

```
var bar = new Bar();
bar.Name = "foo";
var context = new Context();
context.Bars.Add(bar);
```

Surprisingly, querying `context.Bars`, the just added entity cannot be found

```
var howMany = context.Bars.Count(b => b.Name == "foo");
// howMany == 0
```

After `context.SaveChanges()` the same line will result `1`

The `DbSet` seems unaware to changes until they're persisted on db.

Fortunately, each `DbSet` has a [`Local`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbset-1.local?view=efcore-2.1) property that acts like the `DbSet` itself, but it reflect all in-memory operations

```
var howMany = context.Bars.Local.Count(b => b.Name == "foo");
// howMany == 1
```

You can also use `Local` to add entities

```
context.Bars.Local.Add(bar);
```

and get rid of the weird behavior of Entity Framework.

Comment: does this return both the Added but unsaved and the items from database?

Comment: `context.Bars.Local` is initially empty, until `context.Bars` is loaded from database. It can then have both in-memory items and items from database. It is not recommended to use Local on a large dataset. More info about Local: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592872

Comment: Is this specific to a version of EF past 4? I do not have a `Local` property on my `ObjectSet`, but I also have `ObjectSet` and `ObjectContext` objects, not `DbSet` and `DbContext`.

Comment: @Aximili can you explain this please: "until context.Bars is loaded from database". How can I trigger that? I want to query both memory and db

Answer (score 1):

In hibernate transient instances are already attached to context. Just stumbled upon this EF restriction.

I did not managed to intersect/union the `ObjectSet` with its transient entities `ObjectSet.Local` but for our usecase the below find method is sufficient.

*In our cases we create some entities lazy depending on unique criteria during an iteration*

**Find method**

If you are using an repository pattern you can create a method like:

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : class, IEntity
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Finds the unique Entity with the given predicate.
    /// Depending on implementation also checks transient / local (unsaved) Entities.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="predicate"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    IQueryable<T> FindAll(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
}

public class EfRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class, IEntity
{
    protected readonly ObjectContext context;
    protected readonly ObjectSet<T> objectSet;

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new repository of the given context.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context"></param>
    public EfRepository(ObjectContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("Context must not be null.");
        this.context = context;
        this.objectSet = context.CreateObjectSet<T>();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Also takes local context into consideration for unsaved changes
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="predicate"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public T Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        T result = this.objectSet.Where(predicate).FirstOrDefault();
        if (result == null)
            result = this.objectSet.Local().Where(predicate).FirstOrDefault();
        return result;
    }
}
```