# EF4 Not Seeing Changes on context before Save Changes

Tags: c#, entity-framework, c#-4.0, orm

Hi I am using a unit of work pattern on an EF4 context.

The context is being passed across a few methods that all do work on it and then when done I calling save changes.

When I peform a check later on on the state of the object it is the old values not new. yet if i were to call save changes at that point the state I would expect to be seen on the context is saved to the database.

essentially the call stack would be

```
Context ctx;

UpdateItems(ctx);
CheckItemsValid(ctx);
DoSomehtingElse(ctx); //Saving changes here.
```

Now the `CheckItemsValid` is failing as it cant see the changes made in `UpdateItems`, yet it is the same context.

If I wrap the whole thing in a TransactionScope and call SaveChanges before calling check items everything works that seems a bit of a sledgehammer to crack a nut though.

I have tried the following after updating the items in the update items method.

```
ApplyCurrentValues();
Refresh(ClientWins);
AcceptAllChanges();
```

Has any one seen this issue before or do i have to just transact the whole thing and call saves changes mid flow?

```
    using (EntitiesContext ctx = EntityFactory.GetEntitiesContext())
        {

            Repairs.RepairManager repman = new Repairs.RepairManager();

            repman.SetAllRepairsOfTypeToComplete(vehicle.VehicleId, RepairTypes.BodyShop, vehicle.SiteVisitId.Value, technicianId, ctx);


            SchemeManager sm = new SchemeManager();
            result = sm.ProcessVehicle(AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<EFVehicle, AbstractVehicle>(ctx.EFVehicles.Single(p => p.VehicleID == vehicle.VehicleId), new Vehicle()), ref intrules, userId, ctx, false);


            if (result == true)
            {
                ctx.SaveChanges();         
            }
```

is the base of it the processvehicle call checks that SetAllRepairsOfTypeToComplete was successful

Set all repairs to complete simply updates an bit from true to false on the Repairs list that is on the context ctx.EFRepairs.

```
  var cancelledrepairs = ((EntitiesContext)Context).EFRepairs.Where(p => p.VehicleID == vehicle.VehicleId && p.VehicleSiteVisitID == vehicle.SiteVisitId
            && p.RepairTypeID == (int)RepairTypes.BodyShop && p.RepairStatusID == (int)RepairStatusEnum.Cancelled).Count();

        var completedMechrepairs = ((EntitiesContext)Context).EFRepairs.Where(p => p.VehicleID == vehicle.VehicleId && p.VehicleSiteVisitID == vehicle.SiteVisitId
            && p.RepairTypeID == (int)RepairTypes.BodyShop && p.RepairStatusID == (int)RepairStatusEnum.Completed).Count();

        var CurrentMechanicalRepairs = ((EntitiesContext)Context).EFRepairs.Where(p=> p.VehicleID == vehicle.VehicleId && p.VehicleSiteVisitID == vehicle.SiteVisitId
            && p.RepairTypeID == (int)RepairTypes.BodyShop).Count();

        if ((completedMechrepairs + cancelledrepairs) == CurrentMechanicalRepairs)
            return true;
        else
        {
            failureMessage = "Not all mechanical repairs for this vehicle are complete";
            return false;
        }
```

The completedMechrepairsCount is always 0 even though they were updated in SetAllRepairsOfTypeToComplete on the same context.

Comment: Could you post some code for us to go on?

Comment: @jmrnet Updated to show the process in question.

Comment: Ok.  How is the check in ProcessVehicle checking "success"?  Can you show me that code?

Comment: @jmrnet Added the check code ignore the mech messages its just copy and paste stuff that hasn't been fixed up yet :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work in principle.  I even created a local test that mimics this behavior and it worked for me.  I think that the most likely causes are: (any/all)

1)  Your SetAllRepairsOfTypeToComplete method isn't updating the object(s) you think it is.

-or-

2)  Your query to get the completedMechrepairs count isn't picking up the correct object(s).

Try doing some debugging where your EFRepair object has a unique ID that you can use to see if it gets updated.  Then get a List back from your completedMechrepairs check and see if that EFRepair object with that ID is in the list.

Comment: I'll take a look today. I traced the call in and the context seems to be the same one but now I'm awake I'll take another look and report back :)

Comment: found out what is happening but cant figure out why. The cancelledrepairs and completedmechrepairs are making calls to the db currenmechrepairs doesnt hit the db and use the object list in the statemanager that is very odd behaviour!

Comment: Are you saying that right now it is hitting the database rather than the statemanager in your completedMechrepairs count?

Comment: yup and nothing I do seems to stop it both the completed and cancelled hit the db. It has nothing to do with the casting of the context. I replicated the code before the context was cast and the result was the same 2 db hits for the other 2 queries.

Comment: Ah!  Check out this post.  I think you will find your answer in there.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6990618/querying-objects-after-addobject-before-savechanges