# Entity framework query on just added but not saved values

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, savechanges

I'm using Entity Framework from a couple of years and I have a little problem now.

I add an entity to my table, with

```
Entities.dbContext.MyTable.Add(obj1);
```

and here ok.

Then, I'd like to make a query on MyTable, like

```
Entities.dbContext.MyTable.Where(.....)
```

The code above will query on my MyTable in the db.

Is there a way to query also on the just added value, before the **saveChanges**? (obj1) How?

*UPDATE*

Why do I need this? Because, for each new element I add, I need to edit some values in the previous and the next record (there is a datetime field in this table)

*UPDATE2*

Let's say I have to add a lot of objects, but I call the saveChanges only after the last item is added. Every time I add the new item, I read its datetime field and I search in the database the previous and the next record. Here, I edit a field of the previous and of the next record. Now, here is problem: if I insert another item, and, for example, the next item is "Obj1", I have to find and edit it, but I can't find it since I haven't saved my changes. Is it clearer now?

Comment: Why would you want to? You have the object already, it's stored as `obj1`

Comment: As soon as you call SaveChanges obj1 will contain anything just saved, such as it's primary key - no need to re-fetch it.

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre I edited the question to answer you :)

Comment: @PieroAlberto I'm still confused, you have the object so you can still use it to edit other values

Comment: @Darren Not necessarily if there are triggers on the database for creationDate or other calculations the object would have to be reloaded in order to get those values.

Comment: @JaredStroeb - perhaps, though he updated the Q after I made my comment. He needs to put far more information in the Q.

Comment: Yeah still not clear on what the goal is.  Why can you not get your IQueriable collection from the db add the obj1 to the collection then use the collection to find and manipulate  the correct entities?

Comment: Guys, I made another update, I hope it's clear now :)

Comment: _"I edit a field of the previous and of the next record"_ - how do you define "previous" and "next" - by Id, by Date, by table order or…?

Comment: @stuartd Sorting them by a datetime field

Comment: @PieroAlberto in which case you can query for those records, amend them accordingly, and then save all three..?

Comment: @stuartd often. When users add some manually data in a auto-populated table, I have to edit the next and previous one, according to a datetime field, to keep the correct order

Comment: Is that something that could be done by a database insert trigger?

Comment: @stuartd unfortunately nope

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You should be able to get your added entities out of the dbContext via the change tracker like this:

```
 var addedEntities = dbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries()
   .Where(x => x.State == EntityState.Added && x.Entity is Mytable)
   .Select(x => x.Entity as MyTable)
   .Where(t => --criteria--);
```

Or using the [type testing with pattern matching in c# 7.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast#type-testing-with-pattern-matching):

```
var addedEntities = dbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries()
   .Where(x => x.State == EntityState.Added && x.Entity is Mytable t && --test t for criteria--)
   .Select(x => x.Entity as MyTable);
```

because you are only querying added entities, you can combine this with

```
dbContext.MyTable.Where(t => --criteria--).ToList().AddRange(addedEntities);
```

to get all of the relevant objects

Comment: This is good solution.  However it did not work for me, as is.  In my case the Entity.GetType().Name was appended with a GUID.   So I consider the BaseType as well.         Where(x => x.State == EntityState.Added && (x.Entity.GetType() == typeof(MyTable) || x.Entity.GetType().BaseType == typeof(MyTable)))

Comment: Can you give an hint here about the "addedEntities"? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41982691/one-databse-two-applications-two-dbconterxt

Comment: Is there any way you can accomplish this without using ChangeTracker?

Comment: @onhax I don't think there's an easy method. `ChangeTracker` is what EF uses internally I believe

Comment: The `Local` property of `DbSet<T>` described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/8468456/548020 might be a more convenient alternative

Answer (score 3):

I think this is a good situation for Transactions. I am going to assume you are using EF 6 since you did not provide a version. =)

UPDATE2 changes

```
public void BulkInsertObj(List<TEntity> objList)
{
    using (var context = new dbContext()) 
    { 
        using (var dbContextTransaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction()) 
        {  
            try 
            { 
                foreach(var obj1 in objList)
                {
                    dbContext.MyTable.Add(obj1);

                    //obj1 should be on the context now 
                    var previousEntity = dbContext.MyTable.Where(.....) //However you determine this
                    previousEntity.field = something

                    var nextEntity = dbContext.MyTable.Where(.....) //However you determine this
                    nextEntity.field = somethingElse
                }

                context.SaveChanges(); 
                dbContextTransaction.Commit(); 
            } 
            catch (Exception) 
            { 
                dbContextTransaction.Rollback(); 
            } 
        } 
    } 
}
```

[MSDN EF6 Transactions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn456843(v=vs.113).aspx)