# One database, two applications, two dbContext

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, entity-framework, dbcontext

My colleague and me developed a software, divided in two parts. The first is a WPF program while the second is a windows service.

Both of them work on the same database and have their entity framework context.

It works, but now I have to add a new feature giving us some troubles.

I get the addedEntities to do some stuff on it before the saveChanges:

```
var addedEntities = Entities.dbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(x => x.State == EntityState.Added && x.Entity.GetType().Name == "mytable").Select(x => x.Entity as mytable).ToList();
```

This works fine until the windows service writes something in the database. It's like it changhes the dbContext and my program doesn't see the addedEntities anymore.

Do you know how to avoid this issue?

Comment: Do you mean that addedEntities don't appear for items added via the windows service? If so, it's because it's a different context/application. You would need to have the same code executed in the windows service. Alternatively, you could have a trigger/something else that is run in the windows service that populates a different table with anything being inserted, and the WPF app could poll that and then process the newly added records - either deleting or setting some status to processed when it's done.

Comment: Nope. I know what you say. The problem is: in my WPF I have my own addedEntities. The service writes something else, I don't mind what. The WPF losts the addedEntities. Why?

Comment: Ah right - sorry. Not sure what would cause that, are you recreating your DBContext?

Comment: Yes, every program (wpf and service) have they own dbContext but, as I see, when one modifies their own dbContext, it also flush the "addedEntities" of the others.....

Comment: Worth considering if the dbcontext is created on a per call basis in the windows service.