# Does SingleOrDefault look up both in database and in memory?

Tags: entity-framework, linq

Suppose that the table "Items" is empty and then the following code is executed:

```
 var codes = new List<string>{ "aaa", "aaa" }

 foreach (var code in codes) 
 {
    var item = dbContext.Items.SingleOrDefault(r => r.Code.Equals(code)); // (*)

    if (item == null) 
    {
        item = new Item();
        item.code = code;

        dbContext.Items.Add(item);
    }
 }

 dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

**Question:**

The resultant table "Items" will contain two "aaa" items or just one?

That is: in the second iteration the SingleOrDefault query (*) will search both in memory and db? or only in db?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Querying objects after AddObject before SaveChanges?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6990618/querying-objects-after-addobject-before-savechanges)

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj592872(v=vs.113).aspx